# Generic you and notions of a fourth-person

Tags: person

A colleague used the word "you" in a way that I wanted to point out and clarify. Doubtful that "second-person indeterminate" was correct, I searched for an answer and landed on a Wikipedia page titled, [*Generic you*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you).

It starts by stating, "In English grammar, the personal pronoun *you* can often be used in the place of *one*, the fourth-person singular impersonal pronoun, in colloquial speech."

**Questions**

1. Is the "generic you" an accepted term for this usage of the second person?
2. The quoted statement from Wikipedia seems to imply that "you" can also be referred to as the "fourth-person singular impersonal pronoun." Is that correct? Answers on this site refer to the fourth-person as a way of considering the "proximate" and the "obviative." That seems separate and distinct from the intent of "you" when it's used as an indistinct way of referring to habit and custom.

Comment: "Fourth person" just doesn't make sense linguistically. First person is speaker(s). Second person is listener(s). Third person is anyone who doesn't fit either of those. There's no one left for there to be a fourth person.

Comment: @curiousdannii And yet, if you check a corpus of English, you'll find scattered references to this idea outside of academic journals. For instance, this article in The Chronicle of Higher Ed.: https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/being-an-antecedent

Comment: I can't read that link. What does it say about a "fourth person"?

Comment: @curiousdannii "Some languages, like Navajo (Diné Bizaad), have a distinction between third person and fourth person (though in Navajo it is expressed in verb inflections, not pronouns of different shapes). The meaning difference is subtle; some sources say that definitely identified individuals get third person and vaguely delineated or inferred individuals get fourth person. Apparently when talking to others about a man who happens to be present, it is courteous to refer to him with fourth person, which sort of keeps the reference at arm’s length. I’m unqualified to give further details..."

Comment: Third person can be divided into subcategories, but they're still all third person. But I guess if a language has clearly divided morphology it might make sense to call it a "fourth" person, even though it isn't really.